# Get stacktrace for Ember Application in in production mode

Tags: javascript, debugging, ember.js, try-catch, ember-data

I am trying to debug emberjs and ember-data application in production server. I am listening on window.onerror so when something breaks I get callback where I can error message, line no and file. But window.onerror behavior is not same across different browsers. Also it doesnot provide stacktrace

So I am using the below function to wrap the ember boundary functions so I can get full stack trace.

```
function tryCatchWrapper (func, name) {

  // Else wrap the function and return it
  function wrapped() {
    try {
      return func.apply(this, arguments);
    } catch (e) {
      // Report the errors
      console.log((name ? name + ": " : "") + e.message);
      // Get stacktrace
      throw e;
    }
  }
  return wrapped;
};
```

So what all functions I can wrap using above function so as to get information about all the errors happen in the application without affecting anything?

**UPDATE**

Added [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/devilankur18/BM6b4/)

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the [Ember.onerror](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.html#event_onerror) event?

Cfr [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14349428/1373178)

Comment: I have added a jsfidle, The onerror doesnot not work for all the cases. One of such case is reproducible in fiddle.